# Limit Socket to send specific ammount of packets every second in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm programming a simple script in perl that do the following:

1. Open a socket to a specific server
2. Reads data line by line from a big file using a while loop
3. Send data using the open socket

I don't report the whole code since it works perfect and could be too long. What I need to accomplish is send an ammount of packets every seconds. For example I would like to limit to send 100 packets per second. This because the loop is so fast and sometime the server goes in congestion.
What I need, is undestand how (and if) I can implement this kind of mechanism. Is not clear for me how to insert code into the while loop to send "X" packets every second. The actual code looks like:

```
Open Socket
Open file containing data to send
while   # Read file line by line
{
Send data to Server
}
```

Thank you, Lucas.

Comment: You can fill a buffer of sorts in your loop, send, sleep a second -- but the software/packages you are using may have that capabiility, like in the answer by [Cyxoi27](http://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B927). Search the docs.

Comment: Do you want to send *exactly* 100 packets per second for a particular reason or is congestion avoidance all you want?

Comment: I would like to add a setting to leave user choose how many message to send per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check [`WWW::Curl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Curl) and use [`CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE.html) to throttle output traffic.